# Create symbol for an inline function/force a body for another language to call

Tags: c

I have a function that's dead simple and should be inlined 100% of the time, so I put it in a header and marked it as inline. I happen to know compilers don't always inline a function if they can't see the function body so that's why I need this to be in a header, since I need this in multiple object files I write inline so it doesn't complain.

Now I have the reverse problem, now only C/C++ can see the function. How do I export it so I can call it in another language? For example even though test uses test2 I can not call it from another language or call it directly from 'another_language.c' even though I wrote out the prototype. The only way I gotten this to work is by duplicating the function (removing the inline keyword) and putting it in a c file that can't see the inline version. Is there any other way?

```
//a.c
inline int test2() { return 3; }
int test() {
    return test2() + 2;
}

//another_language.c
int test2();
int test();
int main() {
    return test() != test2();
}
```

Comment: I'd try adding `extern` in those two function declarations in the main file. BTW, it's a linker issue, not a compiler issue; the compiler shouldn't have any problem with this code.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb wdym? In my example would I put `extern inline int test2() { return 3; }`?

Comment: That's not the main file now is it?

Comment: `extern int test2();` and `extern int test();`.

Comment: Editing another_language.c to test this, I wrote extern on those two functions like you suggested, no luck. I think I need to use macro magic so I don't copy paste code and can have a non inline copy

Comment: What is “another_language.c”? Is it in C or another language? How could you expect another language to inline a function written in C source code?

Comment: @EricPostpischil well that's why I'm asking how to have a non inline copy

Comment: There is no mechanism for inlining functions between languages. To inline a function in another language, write it in that other language using the other language’s inlining mechanism. If the other language does not have such a mechanism, you are out of luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "_another language", another language than C, and if so, which one? Or do you mean another source file, but also in C? Please provide a [mre] of what you want, even if it does not compiler or link.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If you mean that you want the function to be inlined in a program using the library, you are not making a shared library. Try making it a static library or an object file if it's just one source file.

Comment: @personthehuman: I am not the OP, and neither the OP nor I mentioned anything about a library.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, sorry. I think OP is talking about a library though, since he want's to access his functions from another programming language.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I ended up implementing my solution today. What I mean is if I have `inline` so I can get the functions to inline in my own code the compiler won't produce a body for other object files to link to. I obviously can not use the C headers/inline version since its a different language. I ended up putting the code in its own file, #include it in my normal headers, wrote a define so I can hide the functions and used `#define inline` to undo the inlining when I include it again so it can have a body. It works perfectly but it's pretty ugly. I try to avoid macros when I can